# Trying to understand what this code is doing

Tags: numpy

I have a 2D numpy array call `the_array` with shape  (5,10)
I would like to make sure what this piece of code is doing

```
h,w = the_array.shape
mask = np.ones((h,w))
mask[:int(h*0.35),:] =0  #?? what??
the_array = the_array* mask
```

I see that `mask` is an array of the same dimensions all made of 1s but what after that? (it if it any help these arrays are gonna be used as images later)

Comment: It's simply zeroing out the top 35% of the rows (from the beginning) of the initial array.

Answer (score 1):

`mask[:int(h*0.35), :] = 0` is nothing but an assignment which turns the first 35% of rows into zeros. So basically your mask will be 35% zeros and the rest ones. Multiply it with your image (i.e `the_array * mask`) will make the top part of the image completely black, like a naive image filter.